# Error con SQLite con C# - MonoDevelop (Ubuntu)

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, mono

estoy comenzando a programar en C# y usando SQLite. El problema que tengo es que al tratar de acceder a una tabla ocurre un error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La conexión con la base de datos se realiza, pero no se encuentra la tabla (que realmente existe)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hace falta mas informacion. La base a la que te conectas es realmente esa?? si preguntas por el catalogo de esa base en tu programa la tabla existe??

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: En la medida de lo posible, intenta poner directamente el código en lugar de poner imágenes, a veces con esto es más fácil identificar qué partes de código con las que necesitan ser mejoradas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para trabajar con SQLite.Net vas a necesitar crear una clase cuyas propiedades coincidan con los campos de tu tabla **creyente**. Ej:

```
public class creyente{
   public int id { get; set;}
   public string nombre { get; set; }
   public string apellido { get; set; }
}
```

y después registrar la tabla con el método `CreateTable`.

```
conn.CreateTable<creyente>();
```

Este método busca la tabla y la usa. En el caso de que no exista, la crea.

Por último puedes agregarle atributos a tu clase para mejorar la integración:

```
[Table]
public class creyente{
   [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
   public int Id { get; set;}
   [MaxLength(50)]
   public string nombre { get; set; }
   [MaxLength(50)]
   public string apellido { get; set; }
}
```